# Compile Java Programs on Unix Terminal on WINDOWS

Tags: java, windows, unix, compiler-construction, javac

I am using [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), a friendly Unix terminal that runs on Windows. I want to compile a simple Java program using the `javac` command. After looking at plenty of other forums, I know I need to use the path where Java is installed, but no matter what I try, I keep getting the error

> javac command not found

on the terminal. Can someone please help me out with compiling basic Java programs from within their directory on a Unix terminal on Windows?

And yes, I have JDK for Windows installed on my computer, I just don't know how to use it when compiling through the terminal.

Comment: What are the things you have tried? Perhaps we can point you where you're going wrong. Does your `PATH` include where `javac` is?

Comment: Have you already tried including <java_install_dir>/bin in your PATH env variable? Are you quite sure you installed the JDK and not the JRE?

Comment: are you having a session with a remote Unix machine. make sure you install java on that remote Unix machine and set the path correctly. Install java on Local machine can't help. try echo $PATH

Comment: This worked for me: `export PATH=$PATH:/drives/c/Applications/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin` and then 
`javac`  (Note that a path on the C: drive must start with `/drives/c` like I have it above and that it must have forward slashes - of course the actual directories will differ)

Comment: The tools is probably based on cygwin. The path may be cygwin style.  (See  Jerry Jeremiah 's comment) See docs : http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/support/documentation.html#2_1

Comment: @morgano That was precisely the problem. I was using the javac from jre instead of the javac from jdk.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I did this and javac works, but everytime I close and then reopen MobaXterm, it requires me to export this location to my path again. Do I really need to be adding this location to my path every single time I use MobaXterm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, MobaXterm does not preserve Windows `PATH` environment variable: this is why you obtain

> command not found

when running `javac`.
In order to tell MobaXterm to preserve Windows `PATH`, you just have to go to **Settings** --> **Configuration** --> **Terminal** tab and check **Append Windows PATH environment variable** option.

Comment: This works to an extent. I can add the path to my javac in jdk to my existing path in MobaXterm. However, this does not save everytime I close and reopen MobaXterm. How do I save that path change?

Comment: You may add the following command to your "/home/mobaxterm/.profile" script:
export PATH="$PATH:/drives/c/your/path/to/java"
If the ".profile" file does not exist, you should create it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cygwin first of all. Is another terminal that runs on windows. 
With this command 'sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk' at linux installs the jdk 
And after this you can compile your program. sudo is for administration privilages.

Comment: Cygwin isn't Linux. Apt-cyg is the equivalent, or the normal setup program- that said, you *could* still use the existing jdk.